# How to make a Slack app independent of my account

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm making a Slack app (basic webhook for our CI to send Slack updates) to replace one that broke/disappeared when a colleague who created the Slack app left the company. But I realized, won't the app I'm making need to be replaced again when I one day leave the company (since it seems Slack apps are tied to the creator's account)?

So is there a way that I can setup this Slack app independent of my account so that it wouldn't be deleted with my work Slack account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice to do so is **by creating a Service Account.**

 *(Service accounts are a special type of non-human privileged account used to execute applications and run automated services, virtual machine instances, and other processes.)*

Use this 'Service Account' for creating new apps and add people working on these apps as 'Collaborators'.

Comment: To be clear though, whilst creating a service account is definitely a good idea, there's no such type of user officially. From a Slack perspective (billing/admin/creation etc), it's just another user.